# Mudar a figura do aDetail firemonkey

Tags: listview, firemonkey

Gostaria de mudar a figura do ListBoxItem.ItemData.Accessory para uma figura do imagelist ou outra carregada de um arquivo.

Alguém sabe como mudar?

ListBoxItem.ItemData.Accessory := TListBoxItemData.TAccessory(i)

Para

ListBoxItem.ItemData.Accessory := Imagelist.picture.....

Ou colocar o ícone do ListBoxItem.ItemData.Accessory.aDetail do IOS

Desde já agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Ola eu uso da seguinte forma, crio um `imagelist`, coloco a imagem que quero
e no `OnUpdateObject` do `listview`, informo quem vai receber a imagem:

```
img := AItem.View.FindDrawable('imgFundo') as TListItemImage;
img.ImageIndex := 0;
```

lembrandp que estou usando uma lista dinamica.